# What is the meaning of this expression in sass: $someName: <%= someName %>

Tags: css, sass

What is the meaning of this expression in Sass?

```
$someName: <%= someName %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= someName %>` is not SASS code. 
It looks like it might be some other language that is used to pass a variable to SASS.

I know in ASP, `<%= someName %>` is used to print out a varname.

Comment: Thanks for answer...